# Points to consider while building a home server

Tags: windows-server-2008, web-server, web-hosting

I want to create a home server which can host websites i build.

I want it as a windows server and work the same as servers we get from hosting companies, what main points i should consider while thinking in that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Power consumption
- Power reliability (UPC needed?)
- Many home network connections are asynchronous (DSL, Cable), meaning the upload rate is much smaller than the download rate.
- You need a proper DMZ network layout, protecting your home network from the outside while allowing access to your server
  .
  .
  .

Answer (score 0):

By "work the same" I'll assume you're referring to software.  If that's the case, get a copy of Windows Server and install on the box and configure the services the way you want them.  For the box itself, the specs should be whatever will handle your application with some room to grow.

Since it's a server, you'll want it running 24/7, so power consumption, heat, and noise will be your biggest concerns.  You'll want something relatively quiet that can perhaps live under a desk.  You'll want a battery backup/surge protector for power conditioning.  I'd recommend putting any network gear on battery backup as well to keep the connection alive during a spike or brownout.

A stable Internet connection with static IP addresses will also be in order, preferably with business class support.  You can do it with dynamic IP addresses, but it's not ideal and would require a [dynamic DNS service](http://www.dtdns.com) to operate.

Frankly, with the cost of VPS (virtual private servers) systems as low as they are, I'm not sure I would bother with an Internet server at home without a really compelling reason.

Answer (score 0):

Until recently, I ran a Windows server out of my home, but after a particularly nasty malware infection, I reinstalled with Ubuntu Server.  Its totally CLI, which has been a fun, fascinating learning experience for me.

Ok..back to you..You will need to run a web host, like Apache.  A database server, like MySQL.  And a scripting language, like PHP.

You may also want FTP access to upload new sites/pages/whatever.

Also, I prefer remote access so that I can shove my server in a closet and forget about it, no monitor, keyboard, mouse to worry about.

Good luck.